# Duistermaat-Heckman integral formula on compact manifold with boundary

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, cohomology

Let a compact Lie group $G$ acts on a closed symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$. If the action is Hamiltonian with $\mu$ the moment map, then the integral $$\int_M e^{i\mu (X)+\omega}$$ is equal to the first term in the stationary phase approximation.

My question is if there is a similar integral formula for a compact $M$ with boundary.

Comment: Yes, at least when the boundary is $G$-invariant  and   there are no fixed points on the boundary.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Can you give a reference for the case you mentioned?

Comment: The usual proof uses the fact that, outside  the fixed point set the integrand  can be written as the differential of an *explicit* form $\theta$ of degree $2n-1$, $2n=\dim M$. Denote by $T_r$ the tube of radius $r$ around the fixed point set. The integral is the equal to the integral of $\theta$ over the boundary of $M$ minus the integral over the boundary of $T_r$.  Next let $r\to 0$ and argue as in the boundaryless case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the paper by [E. Prato and and S. Wu](http://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9307005.pdf), 1993 which deals with (at least) a special case of this.